# I want to get between 2 commas in each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get between 2 commas in each line. My example **data.txt** like this :

```
"",ID SURNAME NAME,1st Midterm
1,9002131225 name1 surname1,90
2,9034623973 name2 surname2,80
3,9082135314 name3 surname3,50
```

Example **output.txt** :

```
9002131225 name1 surname1
9034623973 name2 surname2
9082135314 name3 surname3
```

how can I do that in python? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data format as shown in the example is csv with values `ID SURNAME NAME` belonging to one column. If you are ok with extra dependency on pandas, then you can:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("data.txt")['ID SURNAME NAME'].to_csv(
    "output.txt", index=False, header=None)
```

Or using just string manipulation

```
with open("data.txt") as fp:
  txt = fp.read()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
  _ = [f.write(x.split(",")[1]+"\n") for x in txt.split("\n")[1:]]
```

Comment: very nice use of pandas here, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split(',')` in python3 without using any library:

```
string = "1,9002131225 name1 surname1,90"
data = string.split(',')
print(data[1])
```

output:

`9002131225 name1 surname1`

Answer (score 1):

Read about loops and string manipulation, these are Python basics.

A combination of [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) you can do the following:

```py
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       print(s.split(",")[1])
```

You should attempt to write code and ask for feedback when you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

With python capability to read the Input_file, could you please try following, written and tested in Python3. Python program name is `scr.py`, file from where input is being read is `Input_file` and program will write output to `outputFile`.

```
cat scr.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open('outputFile', 'w') as f_out, open('Input_file') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        new_str = "".join(line.split(',')[1:-1])
        f_out.write(new_str + '\n')
    f_out.close()
```